# Adding UIImageView dynamically in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a UITableView to display some information about the consequences of driving to fast: What the fine is going to be etc. I also use some red "dots" that you get in your driving licence. Since this can be between 0 - 6 for each row I have done the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

// Code if no cell is available in the que

// End of that code

UIImage *seniorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ticket_dot.png"];

if (seniorDots == 0) {

} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < seniorDots; i++) {
        UIImageView *seniorImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0 + (i * 15.0), 40.0, 15.0, 40.0)];
        seniorImageView.image = seniorImage;
        seniorImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:seniorImageView];
        [seniorImageView release];
    }
}
```

seniorDots is a variable that I get from a plist file. The code is working as intended but as you may see I have no way of removing them. So the first time I open the tableview I see the expected view, but if I scroll up again the code just keep adding UIImageViews on the cell, not removing the old ones. How can I reference these dots to remove them from screen before adding new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put below code inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

//Remove Other Data

```
   for (UIImageView *img in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [img removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

I hope it will be helpful to you. Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Comment: iOS Developer: Thank you, this is kind a dirty though. If I had other UIImageViews in the cell which did not change it would not do the trick properly. But in this case it works, however you got some errors in the code but I understood what you meant. I will accept it since it works if nobody else has a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIImageView *imgView; 
if(cell == nil)
{
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

 imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,0,100,62)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
imgView.tag = 55;
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
} 
else
{
    imgView = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:55];
}
```